# F# extracting tuple from list of tuples

Tags: f#

I have a list of `clients`, which consists of a `string * int * string * int * string list`. I've made a function where I give a `string`, an `int` and a `string list`. Given some rules, I extract the correct tuple from the list.

An example of three `clients`:

```
let client1 = "Jon", 37514986, "Male", 1980, ["Cars"; "Boats"; "Airplanes"]
let client2 = "Jonna", 31852654, "Female", 1990, ["Makeup"; "Sewing"; "Netflix"]
let client3 = "Jenna", 33658912, "Female", 1970, ["Robe Swinging"; "Llamas"; "Music"]
let file1   = [client1; client2; client3]

//Response must be client(s) with different sex, age diff <= 10 and least one common interest
let request (sex:string) (yob:int) (interests:string list) =
    Set.fold (fun x (nm,ph,sx,yb,toi) -> if sex<>sx && 
                                            yb-yob < 10
                                            then (nm,ph,sx,yb,toi) else x) ("",0,"",0,[]) (Set.ofList file1)

request "Male" 1976 ["Paper"; "Llamas"; "Space"] //Expected ("Jenna", 33658912, "Female", 1970, ["Robe Swinging"; "Llamas"; "Music"])
```

So, I guess you can call it kind of a dating bureau. In the above example, I request all clients, which do not share the same sex as me and do not have an age difference larger than 10. I'm not using `interests` as of now, as I'm still working on that, but it should compare the given interests and the interets of a `client` and see if there's at least one similarity.

But my current problem is that it stops and returns at the first compatible client, but what if there's more? How do I make it continue and build up a set of clients?

I was trying to do something with `Set`, hence the `Set.ofList`, but I'm somehow not feeling I get any of the benefits out of using a `Set` as it is right now.

Comment: Have you looked at `List.filter`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always get confused when using n-tuples (here: quintuple) with n > 3 or non-unique types. Records are much easier to understand:

```
type Sex = Male | Female
type Client = { name: string; id: int; sex: Sex; YearOfBirth: int; interests: Set<string> }
```

constructing values is a bit more verbose then:

```
let client1 = { name = "Jon"; id = 37514986; sex = Male; YearOfBirth = 1980; interests = ["Cars"; "Boats"; "Airplanes"] |> Set.ofList }
let client2 = { name = "Jonna"; id = 31852654; sex = Female; YearOfBirth = 1990; interests = ["Makeup"; "Sewing"; "Netflix"] |> Set.ofList }
let client3 = { name = "Jenna"; id = 33658912; sex = Female; YearOfBirth = 1970; interests = ["Robe Swinging"; "Llamas"; "Music"] |> Set.ofList }
let file1   = [client1; client2; client3]
```

If you really need to list many values in code, create a helper function (or constructor) mapping tuples to the record.
When filtering the list, you can then match on just the values you need (note that `name` is not used):

```
let request sex yob interests =
    file1
    |> List.filter (fun { sex = s; YearOfBirth = y; interests = i } ->
        sex <> s && abs(yob-y)<= 10 && i |> Set.intersect interests |> (not << Set.isEmpty))

request Male 1976 (["Paper"; "Llamas"; "Space"] |> Set.ofList)
```

> `val it : Client list =
>     [{name = "Jenna";
>       id = 33658912;
>       sex = Female;
>       YearOfBirth = 1970;
>       interests = set ["Llamas"; "Music"; "Robe Swinging"];}]`